# Airflow Database connction Ad hoc querie getting error "ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure"

Tags: oracle, airflow

In airflow connection to Oracle database getting error as ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure.
telnet working from ubuntu where airflow is installed so I don't think any firewall issue.
Please find the screenshot.

Please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oECyz.png)

Comment: What did you discover when you googled 'ora-12571'?  It could be any number of network issues -- firewalls, router timeouts, host-name resolution, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There was a change in oracle 19 client: Some network stacks do not correctly handle Out Of Band breaks which are enabled by default in Oracle Database 19c. It may be on firewalls, switches or docker, so in this case you just need to add `disable_oob=on` in sqlnet.ora, to disable it.